What can happen if you connect your Android smartphone to a malicious PC?
If we connect an Android smartphone (without root) to a malicious Windows PC, what's the worst that can happen (security-wise)? I'm talking about a connection for transferring files and without ADB. Obviously, it will be possible to read and even overwrite files in the Documents and Pictures folders (for example), but I've noticed that when I connect the smartphone to the PC, the Android/ folder appears, which has three other folders inside: data/, media/ and obb/. I'm worried about this folder:

Does the malicious PC rename folders and files inside?
Can the malicious PC change phone and application settings?
Can the malicious PC affect the integrity of the phone and/or applications?
Does the malicious PC have access to application data, such as passwords, 2FA secrets, etc.?
Can the malicious PC change your Google account settings, for example?

If this happens (connection to the malicious PC), what should be done next? Format the phone? It seems that, for example, if certain folders are renamed, they revert to the old name after restarting (but I'm talking about folders outside the Android/ folder). My main concern is the Android/ folder.

I am going to vote to close this question because it needs clarity. It could be nothing but charging to all of the above... WAY to many variable to answer this accurately. Most modern devices default to charge only, and if file access is needed you much change it to MTP mode, which would allow read/write of data files. To do any real "malicious" actions would require a minimum of ADB access which requires you to allow that to occur at the first time, or specific exploits which may or may not exist/work on your device.

@acejavelin I'm talking about a connection for transferring files and without ADB. I've already edited the question. Thanks for the alert.

Assuming that the phone has MTP enabled by default and the Android device unlocked (lock screen has been "opened") as this is usually required to make MTP work. In such a scenario I see multiple possibilities:
Place malicious APK on Android phone
The most likely case is that the malware tries to drop one or more malicious APK files in your file-system named in a way that some people may open and install it. Without user interaction an APK can not be installed via MTP, therefore the malware always would need the help of a human. PC malware that can also infect a connected Android device exists and has been seen found multiple times, especially banking malware often have mobile versions.
Upload files that trigger vulnerability in Android
Files in the sdcard/shared media section are automatically index by MediaDatabase. Especially in older Android phones there are known vulnerabilities that allow an attacker to execute code by placing certain manipulated files on the phone (e.g. an JPG image or something similar).
Delete files in Android folder
Delete files in one of the app-specific subfolders of the "Android" folder contains a lot of files but usually only non-critical files. Most app developer place critical files inside the app-private folder /data/data/<app packagename> which is not accessible via MTP (and also not via adb on unrooted devices).
Extract files from Android folder
On a lot of devices you can get access to files inside the Android subfolder via MTP. A lot of apps place backup files in their app-specific folder inside the the Android folder. How good those backup files are protected depends on the app. If the backup is encrypted with a long password using a state-of-the art encryption system (and a good user chosen password) then the chance is low to extract data from a back. Otherwise it may contain interesting data for an attacker.
Delete personal files
Deleting personal files such as photos and videos is of course also possible. But usually modern malware only performs action someone can gain some value by. Therefore just deleting personal data is not a good "malware business-case". And ransomware attacks via MTP are difficult and would take a lot of time on most devices.
Extracting private files
Private files may be copied to the PC and then uploaded into some malware cloud if the people behind the malware are searching for victims for blackmailing.
USB Vulnerabilities
Some devices have vulnerabilities that can be exploited via USB. Usually an exploit via USB allows you to execute code on the phone.

You mentioned extracting files from the Android/ folder but you didn't mention changing it; are there only read permissions on the Android/ folder? And if files in the Android/ folder are deleted, is it serious? Are the deleted files "regenerated" after a reboot? Thank you.

@santorini Modifying would also be possible but that would only work if the malware would attack a specific app where it knows the file format of the files stored in the Android folder. If these files are regenerated depends on the app. As users have access there on most phones apps it would be good programming style considering that users may delete these files and thus the app can not rely on their existence.

When connecting an Android smartphone (without root access) to a potentially malicious Windows PC via USB for file transfer, there are some risks to consider:

The malicious PC can read, modify, or delete any files stored on the
phone's external storage (e.g. Documents, Pictures folders) that are
accessible without root permissions. This includes photos,
downloads, some app data, etc.

However, the malicious PC cannot directly access or modify system
files, application data, or other sensitive areas inside the Android/
folder without root access. This includes data/, media/, obb/
and other protected directories.

The PC cannot directly change phone settings, Google account
settings, or install apps/malware on the phone without root access or
user interaction on the phone itself.

If the malicious PC modifies or deletes files on the phone's external
storage, those changes will persist even after disconnecting.
However, system files/directories cannot be permanently renamed or
deleted without root.


To mitigate risks after connecting to an untrusted PC:

Run a reputable antivirus/anti-malware app on your phone to scan for any malicious files that may have been copied to the external storage.

Check for any suspicious files/folders in the external storage directories and delete them if found.

As a precaution, you can factory reset the phone, but this is likely unnecessary if you did not grant root access and only connected for file transfer.


In summary, while data on the external storage is vulnerable, the core Android system, app data, and account settings remain protected from direct modification by an untrusted PC without root permissions or user consent on the phone itself.
Further reading
[1] https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/malware-spreading-from-infected-android-phone-to/aa72e3ec-f3f4-40d9-bdec-7677c44ba060
[2] https://superuser.com/questions/413730/can-an-infected-android-mobile-phone-infect-a-pc-running-either-windows-or-linux
[3] https://www.reddit.com/r/antivirus/comments/pb94ex/can_malware_go_from_a_computer_to_an_android_phone/
[4] https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Android-Phone-to-Computer
[5] https://askleo.com/can-my-pc-get-a-virus-from-my-smartphone/

I can see the contents of the Android/ folder on my computer (without root and ADB).
